# Register array of async components using dynamic import in Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, import, vuejs3

I have a library that I import many components from and I would like them registered as async components at once without having to type it for each of them manually and I can't import them all as the library exports not just components.

My solution was to put the names of modules in an array

```
    const imports = [
    'CompA',
    'CompB',
    'CompC',
    'CompD',
    ];
```

And then I tried to register individually using for each and dynamic imports.

```
imports.forEach((subComponent) => {
    const component = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
        import('@myLibrary/library').then((comp) => ({
            default: comp[subComponent],
        }))
    );
    app.component(subComponent, component);
});
```

This does not result in an error but with a warning in async wrapper

> ```
> Component is missing template or render function. 
>   at <Anonymous key=10 > 
>   at <AsyncComponentWrapper key=10 >
> ```

I suspect an issue with the dynamic import but unsure how to proceed

When I do it individually like this it works:

```
const Component = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
    import('@myLibrary/library').then(
        (comp) => comp['component']
    )
);
app.component('Component', Component);
```

But it throws a type error when doing it in the forEach

Comment: You have to await your import in the first place. And what is defineAsyncComponent ?

Comment: [DefineAsyncComponent](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#basic-usage) is a vue function that takes a loader function (therefore I should not need to await the import) and loads components only when they are rendered on the page

Comment: You don't have to wrap the component in a `{ default: }` object I think. Have you tried just `.then((comp) => comp[subComponent])`?